# Check if records from one table have same column value in two different dates from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to check which records are related to another record that has the same value in two different dates (any date from 2021 and 2022)

Check which patients were attended in the same medical UNIT in 2021 and 2022.

These are the tables:

PATIENT

| PAT_ID | NAME | LASTNAME | LASTNAME2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PK | VARCHAR | VARCHAR | VARCHAR |
| PK | VARCHAR | VARCHAR | VARCHAR |

ATTENTIONS

| ATT_ID | ATT_DATE | MED_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PK | DATE | FK |
| PK | DATE | FK |

MEDIC

| MED_ID | UNIT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| PK | FK |
| PK | FK |

UNIT

| UNIT_ID | NAME_UNIT |
| --- | --- |
| PK | VARCHAR |
| PK | VARCHAR |

I managed to obtain the desired result using INTERSECT between two queries (I'm not totally sure if it's the best solution)

```
SELECT P.NAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME2 AS PATIENT,  U.UNIT_NAME AS UNIT
FROM ATTENTIONS
JOIN MEDIC M USING (MED_ID)
JOIN UNIT U USING (UNIT_ID)
JOIN PATIENT P USING (PATID)
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTETIONDATE)=2021
INTERSECT
SELECT P.NAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME2 AS PATIENT,  U.UNIT_NAME AS UNIT
FROM ATTENTIONS
JOIN MEDIC M USING (MED_ID)
JOIN UNIT U USING (UNIT_ID)
JOIN PATIENT P USING (PATID)
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTETIONDATE)=2022
ORDER BY 1;
```

RESULT:

| PATIENT | UNIT |
| --- | --- |
| PATIENT_NAME1 | UNIT_NAME |
| PATIENT_NAME2 | UNIT_NAME |
| ... | ... |

However I need to do this using only JOIN operators (any of them.. LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, etc)

Any advice on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @DaleK Oh, sorry. Thank you Dale!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a single pass through the table and counting the occurrence s of the year, eg

```
select *
from (
SELECT P.NAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME2 AS PATIENT,  U.UNIT_NAME AS UNIT, 
  count(case when EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTETIONDATE)=2021 then 1 end) has_2021,
  count(case when EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ATTETIONDATE)=2022 then 1 end) has_2022
FROM ATTENTIONS
JOIN MEDIC M USING (MED_ID)
JOIN UNIT U USING (UNIT_ID)
JOIN PATIENT P USING (PATID)
WHERE ATTETIONDATE between date '2021-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
group by P.NAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME|| ' ' || P.LASTNAME2 ,  U.UNIT_NAME 
)
where has_2021 > 0 and has_2022 > 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify this line `WHERE ATTETIONDATE between date '2021-01-01' and '2022-12-31'` to this one: `WHERE ATTENTIONDATE between to_date('01/01/21','dd/mm/yy') and to_date('31/12/22','dd/mm/yy')` to make it work with Oracle SQL Developer. However, the result should only have the two columns mentioned in the post. I understood the logic of your solution and this may lead to the desired result, If i manage to make it work as expected I will select your answer.

Comment: It was easier than anything i had on my mind... Your answer was very helpful.
I just had to replace `*` with `PATIENT, UNIT` and got the desired result. Thank you!